# Unable to start mongodb with dbpath flag declared

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

```
2017-05-11T12:03:49.700+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=5716 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db/ 64-bit host=localhost
2017-05-11T12:03:49.700+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.0
2017-05-11T12:03:49.700+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 45d947729a0315accb6d4f15a6b06be6d9c19fe7
2017-05-11T12:03:49.700+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2017-05-11T12:03:49.700+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2017-05-11T12:03:49.700+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2017-05-11T12:03:49.700+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2017-05-11T12:03:49.700+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2017-05-11T12:03:49.700+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2017-05-11T12:03:49.700+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2017-05-11T12:03:49.700+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/data/db/" } }
2017-05-11T12:03:49.724+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] Failed to unlink socket file /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock errno:1 Operation not permitted
2017-05-11T12:03:49.724+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28578
2017-05-11T12:03:49.724+0530 I -        [initandlisten] 

***aborting after fassert() failure`enter code here`
```

I am not able to start Mongodb server i tried using service as well and using --dbpath as well i don't know what is the issue. I tried to delete journal files as well but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the file */tmp/mongodb-27017.sock* manually and restart the process.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried starting it with Sudo from the terminal like so

```
sudo mongod
```

> this will require your system username and password